# 404 When trying to link to a css file from jsp in Tomcat

Tags: css, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to link my css file (styles.css) to my jsp file (login.jsp), but using html, with the link tag, i can't link the css! Any sugestions? I am sure i am putting the path correctly because i made a (import using jsp expressions) of the css file and i can read it from the login.jsp. It seems like the link tag is not working for jsp. I red alot of questions like mine, but the solutions never worked for me.

Here is the structure of my project:

[image: structure]

My jsp file header,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Authenticator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">

</head>
```

Thanks,
Rodrigo

Comment: please share the jsp code where you are trying to link the css

Comment: Please add your code to your question (ie. how are you linking the two files?)

Comment: `../../css/styles.css`

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Are you sure? Since this is running on a server, I would recommend `/css/styles.css`

Comment: @msrd0 no I am not sure, that is why its in comments and not posted as an answer.

Comment: i've updated, sorry, new at stackoverflow

Comment: ok the code looks gerenally ok, what does your browser tell you when you enter `localhost:8080/css/styles.css` or whatever your server is listening on

Comment: that's strange, according to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Standard_Directory_Layout that should work

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Standard_Directory_Layout - it didn't change

Comment: could it be that your project is not in the tomcat root but somewhere in your own project? because then tomcat will upload that as `localhost:8080/your-project/css/styles.css`

Comment: msrd0, if i put that, it's fine, and my login.jsp (my homepage) appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tomcat server can contain more than one project at the same time. All projects except the one called `ROOT` are then served as `localhost:8080/your-project`. So you can use the following link directive to access your css file:

```html
<!-- for use from everywhere using an absolute path -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/your-project/css/styles.css">

<!-- for use from a specific directory (in this case
     from the project's root) using an relative path -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

Also, you might need to put your jsp files outside of the `WEB-INF` folder , see [the docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Standard_Directory_Layout) for more information.

Comment: I've put that but it's not working, my page appear without any css

Comment: @RodrigoG So calling `localhost:8080/your-project/index.jsp` works but `localhost:8080/your-project/css/styles.css` gives you a 404?

Comment: calling http://localhost:8080/Authenticator/login.jsp doesn't work, but the other yes

Comment: I can't acess any jsp directly from url path when they are inside the WEB-INF folder right?

Comment: @RodrigoG I updated my answer (notice that I misspelled styles.css before my edit)

Comment: @RodrigoG So you put your jsp files in the project's root directory but you still can't access `localhost:8080/Authenticator/login.jsp`, but you can access `localhost:8080/Authenticator/css/styles.css`? Did you try restarting tomcat?

Comment: Moving my jsp files out of the folder WEB-INF and implementing your answer worked! Finally, omg! Thank you sir ! +1